# The smoothness of a set-value function (correspondence)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, set-valued-analysis

I learned the upper-hemicontinuity and L-continuity of set-valued function. 
Are there a definition of smoothness or differentiability of a set-valued function

$$f:\mathbb R\rightrightarrows\mathbb R?$$

(Let's think about one dimensional case at first.)

For example, can we say that, $f$ is smooth if $f(x)=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{f_i(x)\}$ where $f_i:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a family of smooth functions?

Comment: Sure, but there are many definitions floating around. See for instance https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102818218 and the references therein. You will  also find a lot of relevant information in the book "Set-Valued Analysis" by Aubin and Frankowska.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a somewhat vague answer: In order to understand set-valued analysis you should know something about non-smooth analysis. Non-smooth analysis lets you define directional derivatives and sub-differentials for all kinds of maps. One usually starts in the convex case and then goes to locally lipschitz functions (Clarke generalized derivative). Next one finds a very interesting connection between these new derivatives and tangent cone (and thus normal cones). One then defines derivatives of set-valued maps in terms of normal cones to the graph of the map (coderivative) which is defined for *arbitrary(!)* set-valued maps.

tl;dr if you make your notion of differentiablitiy broad enough, everything becomes differentiable.